# FFmpeg capabillities when compiled in LGPL mode

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-processing

I'm searching all over the web to find out what capabillities of the FFmpeg library one loses when he compiles is under the LGPL license. I went deeper on that question, downloaded and checked the license of every library inside FFmpeg and receive that the following internal libs are under the GPL license:

```
frei0r,gnutls,lame,libass,libiconv,rtmpdump,schroedinger,vid.stab,x264,xavs,xvid
```

and the following are under the LGPL license:

```
bzip2,fontconfig,libbluray,libgsm,libtheora,libvorbis,libvpx,opus,soxr,twolame
```

Now, I can go and read the documentation(if any) of those libraries(and I did) but it still 
vague about what capabillities are lost when using it under the LGPL license.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [`LICENSE`](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=LICENSE) file included with your FFmpeg source:

> Specifically, the GPL parts of FFmpeg are:
>
> - libpostproc
> - libmpcodecs
> - optional x86 optimizations in the files   libavcodec/x86/idct_mmx.c
> - libutvideo encoding/decoding wrappers in   libavcodec/libutvideo*.cpp
> - the X11 grabber in libavdevice/x11grab.c
> - the swresample test app in   libswresample/swresample-test.c
> - the texi2pod.pl tool
> - the following filters in libavfilter:
>
>   - f_ebur128.c
>   - vf_blackframe.c
>   - vf_boxblur.c
>   - vf_colormatrix.c
>   - vf_cropdetect.c
>   - vf_decimate.c
>   - vf_delogo.c
>   - vf_geq.c
>   - vf_histeq.c
>   - vf_hqdn3d.c
>   - vf_kerndeint.c
>   - vf_mcdeint.c
>   - vf_mp.c
>   - vf_owdenoise.c
>   - vf_perspective.c
>   - vf_phase.c
>   - vf_pp.c
>   - vf_pullup.c
>   - vf_sab.c
>   - vf_smartblur.c
>   - vf_spp.c
>   - vf_stereo3d.c
>   - vf_super2xsai.c
>   - vf_tinterlace.c
>   - vf_yadif.c
>   - vsrc_mptestsrc.c

Additionally:

> The following external libraries are under GPL:
>
> - frei0r
> - libcdio
> - libutvideo
> - libvidstab
> - libx264
> - libxavs
> - libxvid

See `LICENSE` for more details.

You can also take a look in [`configure`](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=configure) to see what may require `--enable-gpl`.